# WiFi card driver install problems

Tags: wireless, drivers

I have a Linksys Wireless G PCI adapter with drivers for Windows downloaded. I have tried this method:

```
cd /home/username/Desktop/filename/Drivers
```

(*With the correct information, of course*)

I then received an error saying

```
No such file or directory
```

when the drivers are on the desktop. I have partitioned the hard drive, so I have XP and Ubuntu 12.04. The card works perfectly fine on XP, but I would like to get the drivers working for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install those drivers if they don't work out of the box:

1
Plug the Linksys Wireless-G PCI card into the computer and turn the computer on. Log in as normal.

2
Navigate to *"System," Administration," Networking"* and choose the wireless connection you wish to use. If no connection is available and your card is plugged in, continue to Step 3.

3
Click on *"Properties"* and make sure *"Enable this connection"* is turned on.

4
Set *"Configuration"* to *"Static IP address"* only if your Internet Service Provider has given you a static Internet Protocol (IP) address. Enter the IP address in the required field and click "OK."

5
Check to see if your card is supported. If your Linksys Wireless-G PCI card is not supported by the native Linux driver, check to see if your card is supported by "ndiswrapper".

6
Navigate to the *"Applications*" menu and select *"Accessories"* and *"Terminal"* to install ndiswrapper. Enter the command `sudo apt-get install ndisgtk`

7
Blacklist the native network driver by navigating to *"Applications," "Accessories"* and *"Terminal."* This will open a command-line interface.

Enter the command "`echo -e "blacklist bcm43xx\nblacklist b43\nblacklist b43legacy\nblacklist ssb" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.`"

8
Install the Windows drivers by navigating to *"System," "Administration," "Windows wireless drivers"* and following the prompts.

9
Load the new driver module by entering these commands into the Terminal in sequence:

```
"sudo depmod -a"

"sudo modprobe ndiswrapper"
```

10
Repeat Steps 2 and 3. If your Linksys Wireless-G PCI wireless adapter does not work

Read more: How to Set Up a Linksys Wireless-G PCI Card in Ubuntu | eHow.com http://www.ehow.com/how_6821664_set-wireless_g-pci-card-ubuntu.html#ixzz28fKHFr61